# How to set the trigger when field(contain json value) is updated?

Tags: mysql, trigger, json

I have one table in which there is one field called info.This field hold json value. I want to create trigger on this field.I want to split this json format string into record I mean I want to insert new record based on this json field.Is this thing possible?

e.g

```
jsonfield :{"part_req":{"p_id":"111","category":"stock","order_no":"23001"}}
```

I want to save this field 's value in product table

```
Output Should be :
Table : product

p_id -> 111
category -> stock
order_no -> 23001
```

is this things possible through trigger ???